# .NET Reflection: Detecting IEnumerable<T>

Tags: .net, reflection, generics

I'm trying to detect if a particular instance of a Type object is a generic "IEnumerable"...

The best I can come up with is:

```
// theType might be typeof(IEnumerable<string>) for example... or it might not
bool isGenericEnumerable = theType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IEnumerable<object>).GetGenericTypeDefinition()
if(isGenericEnumerable)
{
    Type enumType = theType.GetGenericArguments()[0];
    etc. ...// enumType is now typeof(string)
```

But this seems a bit indirect - is there a more direct/elegant way to do this?

Comment: please see my follow up: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1650310/net-reflection-determining-whether-an-array-of-t-would-be-convertible-to-some-o

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use

```
if(theType.IsGenericType && theType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IEnumerable<>))
{
    Type underlyingType = theType.GetGenericArguments()[0];
    //do something here
}
```

EDIT: added the IsGenericType check, thanks for the useful comments

Comment: if theType is not generic, it will throw an `InvalidOperationException` - not a very good solution for a check IMHO.

Comment: This only works if 'theType' is exactly typeof(IEnumerable<>), not if the type implements the interface. Hopefully that's what you're after.

Comment: The "type" is actually an input parameter type - so I really do want to know if is exactly IEnumerable and not just convertable to IEnumerable... actually, I'm going to ask another question as this one is effectively answered.

Answer (score 4):

You can use this piece of code to determine if a particular type implements the `IEnumerable<T>` interface.

```
Type type = typeof(ICollection<string>);

bool isEnumerable = type.GetInterfaces()       // Get all interfaces.
    .Where(i => i.IsGenericType)               // Filter to only generic.
    .Select(i => i.GetGenericTypeDefinition()) // Get their generic def.
    .Where(i => i == typeof(IEnumerable<>))    // Get those which match.
    .Count() > 0;
```

It will work for any interface, however it will **not** work if the type you pass in is `IEnumerable<T>`.

You should be able to modify it to check the type arguments passed to each interface.

Comment: Instead of Where().Count() you can use Any().

Answer (score 2):

Note that you cannot call `GetGenericTypeDefinition()` on a non-generic type, therefore, first check with `IsGenericType`.

I'm not sure if you want to check whether a type implements a generic `IEnumerable<>` or if you want to see if an interface type is `IEnumerable<>`. For the first case, use the following code (the inner check with `interfaceType` is the second case):

```
if (typeof(IEnumerable).IsAssignableFrom(type)) {
    foreach (Type interfaceType in type.GetInterfaces()) {
        if (interfaceType.IsGenericType && (interfaceType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IEnumerable<>))) {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} implements {1} enumerator", type.FullName, interfaceType.FullName); // is a match
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: is this code referring to the legacy (non-generic) IEnumerable interface?

Comment: Yes, because the generic one implies the non-generic one, it's a quick check to make sure that it is worth going over the interfaces at all. If `IEnumerable` (non-generic) is not implemented, `IEnumerable<>` (generic) cannot be either.