# GetGenericTypeDefinition returning false when looking for IEnumerable<T> in List<T>

Tags: c#, reflection, list, ienumerable

Following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1649888/net-reflection-detecting-ienumerablet), why does `enumerable` in this:

```
Type type = typeof(List<string>);
bool enumerable = (type.IsGenericType && type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IEnumerable<>));
```

return `false`?

---

### Edit 1

As the above doesn't work, what would be the best way to determine if a class implements IEnumerable?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here, I might use `GetListType(type)` and check for `null`:

```
static Type GetListType(Type type) {
    foreach (Type intType in type.GetInterfaces()) {
        if (intType.IsGenericType
            && intType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IEnumerable<>)) {
            return intType.GetGenericArguments()[0];
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Nice one Marc, this was the only one that kept to my requirements and worked for me.

Answer (score 5):

Because

```
(typeof(List<String>)).GetGenericTypeDefinition()
```

is returning

```
typeof(List<>)
```

`GetGenericTypeDefinition` can only return one type, not all the unbound types implemented by the target instance of `Type`.

To determine if `X<T>` implements `IY<T>` either

- Reify T (i.e. make it a real type), and check with concrete types. I.e. does `X<string>` implement `IY<string>`. This can be done via reflection or with the `as` operator.
- `Type.GetInterafces()` (or `Type.GetInterface(t)`).

The second is going to be easier. Especially as this also gives false:

```
Type t = typeof(List<string>).GetGenericTypeDefinition();
bool isAssign = typeof(IEnumerable<>).IsAssignableFrom(t);
```

Comment: Your example, unfortunately, returns false.

Comment: You mean the one where I say just using `AssignableFrom` "*gives false*"?

Answer (score 2):

If you want a quick test for specific closed generic types - for example, to check if `List<string>` implements `IEnumerable<string>` - then you can do something like this:

```
Type test = typeof(List<string>);
bool isEnumerable = typeof(IEnumerable<string>).IsAssignableFrom(test);
```

If you want a more general-purpose solution that works for any `IEnumerable<T>` then you'll need to use something like this instead:

```
Type test = typeof(List<string>);
bool isEnumerable = test.GetInterfaces().Any(i =>
    i.IsGenericType && (i.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IEnumerable<>)));
```

Answer (score 1):

The following returns true and is kind of to the point, checking the interfaces:

```
 enumerable = typeof(List<string>).GetInterfaces()
               .Contains(typeof(IEnumerable<string>));
```